# Transparency incorrect behaviour in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, transparency, unity3d-shaders

Creating two materials with render mode transparent and with two primitives added to the scene I get different faces rendered depending on the distance to the camera.

[image]

Both materials red and blue have the default settings except from being set to transparent render mode.

[image]

If the alpha is set to 1, red face abruptly appears while getting closer.

How to fix this?

Comment: happens quite often especially with large objects having huge triangles .. the renderer determines which one is closer by using AABB so it can easy happen that your cube appears further away or not depending on the perspective .. see e.g. https://answers.unity.com/questions/609021/how-to-fix-transparent-rendering-problem.html